# Python 2.7 multiprocessing Process hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, multiprocessing

I have a 2 classes which inherits from multiprocessing.Process.
One of these classes is responsible for spawning instances of the other.

When I call start() on an instance of this class, python hangs, although only if I haven't specified -O command line argument, in which case it works fine.

I have the following simplified example:

```
class Test(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test,self).__init__(name="test_process")
        #log that we're initialising

    def run(self):
        print "Running Test Process"


class Caller(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Caller,self).__init__(name="Caller process")
       # log initialising
       self.p = Test()

    def run(self):
        print "Running caller"

        if self.daemon:
             print "Caller is daemon"
        else:
             print "Caller is not daemon"
        self.p.start()

        print "Returned from start"

        while True:
           sleep(1.0)
           print "Tick"

        p.join()
```

And I get the following outputs

> > python do_it

```
# Running Caller
# Caller is not daemon
```

and no further output.

> > python -O do_it

```
# Running Caller
# Caller is not daemon
# Returned from start
# Running Test Process
# Tick
# Tick
# ...
```

Does process need optimisations to work? In which case, why is the instance of caller running happily?

Any suggestions for understanding what could be going on here, or pointing out where I have strayed from the way would be gratefully received.

The other factor which may be relevent is this is running on an embedded board, but it still has a few 100MB's of spare ram, so I'd be suprised if this was the issue.

Comment: On normal CPython -O flag just sets `__debug__` to zero and skips `assert` calls, so I would be suprised if this would cause any trouble. What interpreter are you using for embedded board?

Comment: Python -v -V gives "Python 2.7.3" I'm trying to find out how to get more useful info from it

Comment: On the other hand your code works fine with and without -O on my machine (Python 2.7.9)

Comment: I'm not surprised - it doesn't strike me as contentious code. I suspect this is some sort of resource limit thing, but I'd really like to know what is going on.

Comment: Is it always like that? I mean in every run with -O flag it hangs and every run without runs without problem?

Comment: The other way round, but yes: every time.

Comment: oh, so I believe it may be something with asserts in process module. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py
I think it may be line L121, maybe your system for some reason blocks on `os.getpid()`